# Replace json to java string

Tags: java, json, string

Hi Guys I'm new to programming.
In my java code i have string like this.

```
String json ="{"name":"yashav"}";
```

Please help me out to print the values using pre-build java functions.
Expected output should be like below

```
name=yashav
```

Comment: This isn't json. Remove the brackets. Replace the colon...

Answer (score 1):

First of all its not JSON.
If you want to work for actual JSON. There are many libraries which help you to transfer string to object.
GSON is one of those libraries. Use this to covert object then you can use keys to get values. Or you can iterate whole HashMap as per your requirements.
https://github.com/google/gson

Comment: Gson can't parse the above string and seems unnecessary overall

Answer (score 1):

Forst of all, given `String` is **NOT** a `json`. It should be `"{\"name\":\"yashav\"}"`. If you have a **correct json string**, you can use [JacksonUtils](https://github.com/oleg-cherednik/JacksonUtils).

Define a model:

```java
class Url {
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

And parse the `json string`:

```java
String json = "{\"name\":\"yashav\"}";
Url url = JsonUtils.readValue(json, Url.class);
System.out.format("name = %s", url.getName());
```

---

Another way is to use `Regular Expression`:

```java
public static void main(String... args) {
    String url = "{name:yashav}";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\{(?<key>[^:]+):(?<value>[^\\}]+)\\}");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(url);

    if (matcher.matches())
        System.out.format("%s = %s\n", matcher.group("key"), matcher.group("value"));
}
```

---

And finally, you can use plain old `String` operations:

```java
public static void main(String... args) {
    String url = "{name:yashav}";
    int colon = url.indexOf(':');
    String key = url.substring(1, colon);
    String value = url.substring(colon + 1, url.length() - 1);
    System.out.format("%s = %s\n", key, value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**{name:yashav}** this is not a valid JSON format.
If you have {"name": "yashav"} you can use Jackson to parse JSON to java object.

```
class Person {
  String name;
  ...
}

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Person person = mapper.readValue("{\"name\" : \"mkyong\"}", Person.class);
```